# how to access ionic.config.json

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3, ionic-native

Is there a way to access ionic.config.json from a page or a provider in my ionic framework? I need to change proxy settings for android or web accordingly.

this is my ionic info:

```
@ionic/cli-utils  : 1.19.2
ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.20.0
```

global packages:

```
cordova (Cordova CLI) : 8.0.0
```

local packages:

```
@ionic/app-scripts : 3.1.8
Cordova Platforms  : android 7.0.0
Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2
```

System:

```
Android SDK Tools : 26.1.1
Node              : v8.11.1
npm               : 6.0.0
OS                : Windows 10
```

Environment Variables:

```
ANDROID_HOME : C:\Users\themhz\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk
```

Misc:

```
backend : pro
```